# How To Do a Moe-Kill?

Tags: mugen-souls

How do I do a Moe Kill ? Every Monster/Crystal/Object have different Affinity and Emotion.

[image: screenshot of all different monsters, crystals and objects]

Do I follow/use the same affinity as Monsters or the opposite ?

I mean Sadist vs Masochist or Sadist Monster only likes Sadist affinity.